# Is it possible to receive refunds for online purchases to a Thomas Cook foreign exchange card?

Tags: foreign-exchange, debit-card

I've a Thomas Cook foreign exchange card issued in India. While travelling, I'd used it to make an online purchase on Walmart USA. I later returned the item, which made me eligible for refund. Walmart says they refunded the money to my card yesterday. Will such a refund be processed? There is no bank account associated with a forex card, of course, so I'm confused.

Comment: A _credit_ card has no bank account associated with it; a _debit_ card does. When you get a refund to a credit card, the balance due is reduced. If you have a zero balance to start with, you will get a cash refund some time later, not necessarily in US dollars, but in whatever currency you pay your card in. With a debit card, the refund will be deposited back into your bank account. So, what kind of card is your Thomas Cook card?  Hint: check whether you are required to make monthly payments towards the balance of your credit card.

Comment: It's a debit card. You pay in Indian rupees before you travel and get to spend the equivalent in foreign currency when you travel. But it has no account associated to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is usually called a *pre-paid credit card.*  You pay some
money (Indian Rupees) to the credit card company, and then you can use the card to pay for purchases etc in foreign (non-Indian) currencies upto
the *remaining balance* on the card. If a proposed charge exceeds the remaining balance, the transaction will be declined when you try to use the card.

There might be multiple ways that the card is set up, e.g. it might be restricted to charge purchases denominated in US dollars alone, or you might be able to use it anywhere in the world (except India).  The *balance* on the card might be denominated in INR, or in US$, say. In the latter case, the exchange rate at which your INR payment was converted into the $US balance is fixed and agreed to at the time of the original payment: you paid INR 70K (say) and the balance was set to US$ 1000 even though the exchange rate on the open market would have given you
a few more US dollars. In the former case with the balance denominated
in INR, a charge of US$ 100, say, would be converted
to INR at a fixed agreed-upon rate, or at the current exchange rate that the Visa or MasterCard network is using, plus (typically) a 3% fee currency exchange fee, and your balance in INR will decrease accordingly.

With all that as prologue, if you made a purchase from Walmart USA and
later returned it for a credit, it should increase your credit card balance  appropriately. You may be whacked with currency conversion fees along the way depending on how your card is set up, but with a US$-denominated card,
a credit of US$100 should increase your card balance by US$100. So, that $US 100 can be spent on something else instead.

> In short, the *card* is
>   your "bank" account. You cannot spend more than the remaining balance on the card just like you cannot withdraw more money from your bank account than you *have* in the account, and you can recharge your card by making more INR payments into it so as to increase the available balance. But it is like a current account in that you are unlikely to earn interest on the balance the way you do with a savings account.

So what if you are back in India and have no further use of this card? Can you get your balance back as cash or deposit into your regular
bank account? Call the Customer Help line, or read the card agreement you signed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yo do get a refund
Only you have to do some additional work
like call customer care center to get details of  return reference number associated with transaction and have to email it since  techincal team have  do the refund process manually